# Apache Spark subtract days from timestamp column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I am using Spark Dataset and having trouble subtracting days from a timestamp column.

I would like to subtract days from Timestamp Column and get new Column with full datetime format. Example:

```
2017-09-22 13:17:39.900 - 10 ----> 2017-09-12 13:17:39.900
```

With date_sub functions I am getting 2017-09-12 without 13:17:39.900.

Comment: `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(strdate) - 86400  )` to subtract one day. I think you might lose milliseconds this way.

Comment: Thank you. This way is generally ok, but I loose miliseconds this way...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You `cast` data to `timestamp` and `expr` to subtract an `INTERVAL`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

val df = Seq("2017-09-22 13:17:39.900").toDF("timestamp")

df.withColumn(
  "10_days_before", 
  $"timestamp".cast("timestamp") - expr("INTERVAL 10 DAYS")).show(false)
```

```
+-----------------------+---------------------+
|timestamp              |10_days_before       |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
|2017-09-22 13:17:39.900|2017-09-12 13:17:39.9|
+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

If data is already of `TimestampType` you can skip `cast`.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can simply use [date_sub](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_sub) function from pyspark +1.5:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("10_days_before", date_sub(col('timestamp'),10).cast('timestamp'))
```

Comment: Recently discovered that date_sub() returns a date, not a timestamp, and so you'll run into unexpected rounding.