# Python Pyspark: Filter for 1 Day Before Current Date Using F.current_date()

Tags: python, date, pyspark, datediff, subtraction

I want to filter my data set for all the dates before a certain date. Specifically 1 day before the current date.

I tried the code below:

```
df = df.filter(F.col('date') <= F.current_date() - 1)
```

But I got the following error:

```
u"cannot resolve '(current_date() - 1)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(current_date() - 1)' (date and int)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get today -"1 day" date in sparksql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114875/how-to-get-today-1-day-date-in-sparksql) and also perhaps [Apache Spark subtract days from timestamp column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365822/apache-spark-subtract-days-from-timestamp-column).

Comment: You can also use [`F.datediff`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.datediff) for this: `F.datediff(F.current_date(), "date") >= 1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`F.date_sub`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_sub) method should work:

```
df.filter(F.col('date') <= F.date_sub(F.current_date(), 1))
```