# AWS Glue : Filter date field

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, filtering, aws-glue

I have a very basic question, I create a AWS Glue job and I need to create a filter while extracting data from a dynamodb table. I need extract data from previous day only using a field named "time".

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import re

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "sampledb", table_name = "tablex", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")

Transform1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = DataSource0, mappings = [("allresults.paymentCapabilityResult.paymentCapabilityCheckResult", "boolean", "allresults.paymentCapabilityResult.paymentCapabilityCheckResult", "boolean"), ("time", "string", "time", "timestamp")], transformation_ctx = "Transform1")

DataSink0 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = Transform1, connection_type = "s3", format = "json", connection_options = {"path": "s3://xxxxx/output/", "partitionKeys": []}, transformation_ctx = "DataSink0")
job.commit()
```

Comment: How does time look like?

Comment: The dynamodb time field looks like this:

Time String: Thu Sep 03 2020 01:43:52 GMT+000 (Coordinated Universal Time)

In fact the field is defined as string, so I guess first I need to cast to date/time, then do the filter, right?

Comment: Yes, you would need to parse that to timestamp first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filter for yesterday can be easily done in PySpark, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658185/python-pyspark-filter-for-1-day-before-current-date-using-f-current-date). A script would look like this:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = Transform1.toDF()
df = df.where(F.col("time") == F.date_sub(F.current_date(), 1))
Transform2 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glue_ctx=glueContext, name="df")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that.

Comment: I realized that time field in fact is defined as string, so I guess I need first to cast the field as date/time and then do the filter...

Comment: The casting to a timestamp should already have been done at the ApplyMapping step, that looks correct. You can always check the schema of a dataFrame with df.printSchema().